# Select data from mysql using php in between dates got from html form, but date is stored in 3 different columns under day, month, year

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database where i want to select data with date in between dates got from html form .

lets assume database has columns - `custid(int)(5)`,`query(varchar)(100)`,`day(int)(2)`,`month(int)(2)`,`year(int)(2)`.

and i am getting date from form as `dd/mm/yy`

thereby i tried this but it's not working .

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE custid = 'x' AND 
(CONCAT(day'./.'month'./.'year) AS DATE BETWEEN '01/01/01' AND '01/01/99');
```

// where `01/01/2001` is the starting date and `01/01/99` recieved from html form  and **x** is the **custid** recieved from too).

Is there any way around to solve it ?

Error in sql :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '`month`'./.'`year`) AS DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2001' AND
>   '01/01/2099') LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3

Edit 1 :

After looking through concat() function documentation and answer by jens , sql query after updation.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE custid = 'x' AND 
(CONCAT(day','/','month','/','year) AS DATE BETWEEN '01/01/01' AND '01/01/99');
```

Comment: *this but it's not working .* is no error description. Can you explain what is not working? Store dates in a column with a date datatype. convert your dates to a date type i think then it will work as expected

Comment: i have added the error i am recieving from sql

Comment: @jens, for some other reason i have saved it as integer,, is there any other way where i can use the columns and add together like a string and use as a date format

Comment: Fix your schema. Problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing it as dates , i used concat() to use it as a numeric value and then using php functions i converted the date got fro mhtml form into numbers too, and then used simple between function to check if the value is in between the limits.

Then sql becomes

```
SELECT * FROM `ledger-company` 
WHERE `companyid` = '10' 
AND (CONCAT(year,month,day) BETWEEN '010101' AND '990199')
```

Comment: TY @jens for pointing out the syntax error in concat() function

Comment: @nguy for the hint to use compare as numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Your concat Syntax must by:

```
(CONCAT(day','/','month','/','year) BETWEEN '01/01/01' AND '01/01/99');
```

BTW: This makes a string compare not a date compare, so you should Change to a date format.

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('day','/','month','/','year'), '%d/%m/%Y') between STR_TO_DATE('01/01/01' ) and STR_TO_DATE('01/01/99', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

For more informations about the concat syntax see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp
and for str_to_date syntax https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

> Some tips: don't use function or calculation at where clause with
>   column.

In your case:
1. explode date from your form and get 3 part.
2. you can write SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE custid = 'x' AND
(year >= '1' AND year <='99' and month >= '1' and month <= '12' and day >= '1' and day <= '12')
```

Comment: I already tried this, but got into calculation at where clause because , if the date is like `12/12/2018` to `02/02/2019`, then it will not take date with day `13`to`31` and `01` of month `01` in between , that's why i was comparing it as date.

Comment: I'm sorry. You can use SQL like this: year * 1000 + mon * 100 + day and compare, it will faster with cast string to date.

Comment: ummm, you mean like comparing integers ? using `concat()` and making a number and then make number from form date using php function and then compare with between , nice idea though , will try it .